# gestión de fichero .csv

Tags: python, archivo, csv

tengo un atolladero con un ejercicio de ficheros csv en python, la primera parte del ejercicio la tengo resuelta, más la segunda tengo problemas para generar el archivo como pide el segundo apartado del ejercicio, este formato:  {'10T0001C1': ['Principe Pio', 'Aeropuerto']... pego el error [image: error en los campos], necesito alguna sugerencia que me ayude a encontrar la solución, sé que es complicado sin el propio archivo cercanias.csv así que pego una imagen del formato de un elemento de cercanias.csv que recibe el programa[image: imagen de ejemplo]:

```
fichero=open(r"C:/Users/Fran/Desktop/Formacion/python/Programas de clase/cercanias.csv")
def gestion_lineas(fichero):
    datos_total = []
    #cercanias = {}
    cercanias_2 = {}
    texto = fichero.read()
    datos_total = texto.split("\n")
    datos_total.remove(datos_total[0])
   
    for i in datos_total:
        #datos_dict1 = []
        datos_dict= i.split(",")
        #diccionario con extensión de líneas
        ele = datos_dict[0]+datos_dict[1]
        ele2 = datos_dict[2].split("-")
        cercanias_2[ele]=ele2
        
    return cercanias_2
cercanias = {}
cercanias = gestion_lineas(fichero)


with open("cercanias2.csv","w", newline="") as f:
    fieldnames = ["id-linea","estaciones"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    #writer.writerow(gestion_lineas(fichero))
    
    for elem,elem2 in cercanias.items():
        ele = {}
        ele[elem]=elem2
        writer.writerow(ele)
```

Comment: Y que se supone que debes hacer?

Comment: ¿Sabías que puedes ocupar `csv` para **leer** archivos csv? Mucho más simple.

Comment: generar otro archivo .csv bajo el formato  que expongo: {'10T0001C1': ['Principe Pio', 'Aeropuerto']...

Comment: ¿No se supone que el diccionario que pasas `writer` debe tener llaves "id-linea" y "estaciones". Imprime el diccionario `ele` antes de pasarlo a `writer` y fijate que llaves tienes.